# How to figure out the Token Name in the controller?

Tags: laravel, token, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I have created a Laravel 5.4 App, which is a REST based API for serving out data about our inventory to customers.

I have implemented Passport based Authentication, and My customers create a 'Personal Access Tokens' and use that in their client requests. All of this is working fine.

I now need to meter the usage of the API to figure out which user, and which token (by Name) is making the request.

I am able to get the User by using `$request->session();`, but how do I get the name of the Token that is making the request?

Comment: what do you mean by 'get the name of the token? '

Comment: When a User creates a Personal Access Tokens, he or she enters a Name, and that is stored in the `oauth_access_tokens` table. I want to record this name, along with the request, so that I meter these API calls, and at the end of the month send a Bill to the User

Answer (score -1):

Laravel passport searches for valid tokens in 2 locations:

- [the bearer token](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/4.0/src/Guards/TokenGuard.php#L89)
- [a cookie](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/4.0/src/Guards/TokenGuard.php#L91)

When boiled down, you could use this method to find the token you seek:

```
$token = $request->bearerToken() ?? $request->cookie(Passport::cookie());
```

Comment: The clients specify their access token as a Bearer token in the Authorization header of their request. If I use the code in your answer, I get an error saying 'Method bearer does not exist' and the clients are not sending any cookie along with their request.

Comment: could you double check that the class of $request is \Illuminate\Http\Request ?

Comment: edit: my mistake: use ->bearerToken() instead of ->bearer()